# streaming video player / attaching video(not camera) to NetStream in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6, netstream, flash-media-server

I am new to actionscript, basically i am trying to stream video player but we can't use attachVideo in as3 so what can i use instead of attachVideo in following code? Im using flash builder/flex 4.6 . If you could suggest link/tutorial for streaming video player it would be great help. Thank you!

```
   private function initOutStream():void
            {     /* streamOut is NetStream to adobe cirrus , 
                    conn is making connection to adobe cirrus */    
          trace("initOutStream");
          streamOut = new NetStream(conn,NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
          streamOut.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,streamStatus);
          streamOut.publish("media");

                  // mp4 file from local machine

                  nc = new NetConnection();                           
                  nc.connect(null); 
                  ns = new NetStream(nc);
                  ns.play("t.mp4");
                  ns.client = this;

                  var vid:Video = new Video;
                  vid.attachNetStream(ns);

          // streaming vid to media server

                  streamOut.attachVideo(vid);

         var streamOutClient:Object = new Object(); 
         streamOutClient.onPeerConnect = function(farStream:NetStream):Boolean
                   {   
                     return true;         
                   }       
              }
```

error:
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method attachVideo through a reference with static type

Comment: Never seen "attachVideo" method before. Are you trying to create some kind of live webcam sharing app? If you're just trying to stream video you can accomplish this without attachVideo.

Comment: no, i am not trying to attach cam , i want to play .mp4 video from my local machine and stream it p2p to other person.

Comment: attachVideo method http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001694.html but it can't be used in actionscript 3

Comment: There's your answer, fishbulb.

Comment: i am able to play video but i want to stream it to other person using adobe cirrus.. and we can't use attachVideo in actionscript 3.0

Comment: I think you want to use the `attachNetStream()` method of the `Video` object, as shown [here in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html#attachNetStream()).

Comment: when i use  streamOut.attachNetStream(ns); in above code (in as3) it gives error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method attachNetStream through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream. I doubt if we can join two NetStream !!

Answer (score 0):

This is a code i wrote lately for a business job. i hope it helps...

```
var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.width = 640; vid.height = 480;
addChild(vid);

var cnn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
cnn.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(cnn);

ns.play("t.mp4");

vid.attachNetStream(ns);

ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, error);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, streamStatus);

function streamStatus(e:NetStatusEvent){
    //trace(e.info.code);
    if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop"){

    }
}

function error(e){

}
```

Comment: this code will play t.mp4 in swf/browser , i am able to do that but what i am asking is i want to stream this video to other peer using cirrus, so i want to attach this video to streamOut (NetStream to cirrus) in actionScript 3, so i ll have to use like streamOut.attachNetStream(ns); but u cant attach two netStreams i guess... so is there any other way?